# MySQL sorting by votes in another table

Tags: mysql, join

I have tables like this:

```
entries:

ID      TITLE
1       Xyhargka
2       Hypothermia
3       Scale
```

and

```
votes:

ID      VOTE1       VOTE2   USERNAME
1       1           2       Entity
2       1           3       RobertG
```

VOTE1 and VOTE2 have the IDs of entries. VOTE1 counts for 2 votes, and VOTE2 counts for 1 vote.

I'm trying to construct a query that returns this:

```
ID      TITLE           VOTES
1       Xyhargka        3
3       Scale           2
2       Hypothermia     1
```

I've been looking at JOIN statements, but I can't seem to figure it out... I know this isn't valid MySQL, but here's pseudocode of what I want:

```
SELECT v1 + v2 as votes, entries.* FROM entries
    JOIN (SELECT count(vote1) * 2 as v1 FROM votes WHERE vote1 = entries.id)
    JOIN (SELECT count(vote2) * 1 as v2 FROM votes WHERE vote2 = entries.id)
ORDER BY votes
```

Comment: Your desired result does not correspond at all with your input and description of what the votes mean.  Please correct the sample or explain better what you intend.

Comment: @JimGarrison updated... if the pseudocode looks wrong, I'm sure it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it in SQLSERVER, not sure if there are differences for this in MySQL

```
SELECT V.ID,
  SUM( V.COUNT) AS TOTALCOUNT
FROM  (SELECT E1.ID AS ID, 2 AS COUNT
FROM VOTES AS V
JOIN ENTRIES AS E1
  ON V.VOTE1 = E1.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT E2.ID AS ID, 1 AS COUNT
FROM VOTES AS V
JOIN ENTRIES AS E2
  ON V.VOTE2 = E2.ID) AS V
GROUP BY V.ID
ORDER BY TOTALCOUNT DESC
```

Comment: Is this tested? It looks good and it runs, but it's not returning the expected results..

Comment: I need more info than that to help you..  ;)

Comment: Nevermind! It was my problem. Works perfectly, thanks!